# jenkins and android name archive file name

Tags: java, android, jenkins, continuous-integration

I use Jenkins for CI/CD an Android project.

per build APK name is changed. for example:
app_googlePlay_release_2.4.0_(2019_09_21_14_44)
app_googlePlay_release_2.4.1_(2019_09_21_16_00)
app_googlePlay_release_2.4.2_(2019_09_21_16_02)

I use the Install Android Packages plugin in Jenkins.
[image]

I need to use the dynamic name for APK file

F*for example:**

app/build/outputs/apk/googleplay/release/{BUILD_NUMBER}.apk

or

app/build/outputs/apk/googleplay/release/**.apk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This APK file field does not expend variable. you can rename the file when APK file generated, so APK file will get the renamed file for the artefact.

```
 echo "starting generate apk file"
 echo "****************************************"
 ./gradlew  assembleDebug
APK_NAME=${BUILD_NUMBER}
FILE_PATH="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android-app-automation/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/"
FILE="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/android-app-automation/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
if test -f "$FILE"; then
    echo "APK build successfully"
    mv $FILE "${FILE_PATH}${APK_NAME}.apk"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Job failed to create APK... see logs"
    exit 1
fi
```

[image]

Or you can use branch name for APK file

```
APK_NAME=$(echo $source_branch | tr "/" -)
```

[image]